# Highcharts 24 hour setup for hourly values

Tags: highcharts

I want to realize a chart (daily view) where hours start with 00:00, and end with 24:00, with one hour intervals. And showing Y axis values at specific hours like 14:30, 21:25 etc. 
What I successfully reached is showing the Y axis values, but the hours doesn't start with 00:00 and end with 24:00.. and they are kind of shifted, I see a part of the daily "timeline".

I use datetime type for X axis. My guess I have some zooming, or interval issues, tried several possibilities.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code or a jsFiddle of what you've done so far.

Comment: Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/93Xcu/6/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        min: Date.UTC(2013,4,22),
        max: Date.UTC(2013,4,23),
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/93Xcu/7/

Comment: Add to prevent the display of the date:
 dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    hour: '%H:%M',
                    day: '%H:%M',
                }

Comment: @Pawel Fus Hello, i am handling the timezone also with the highchart. The problem is while without adding the offset in UTC the ticks are coming correctly. But, as soon i will add timezone concept the ticks are not getting displayed correctly.